# matrix_exponetial with eigenvectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-exponential

Let $A \in M^{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\{\varphi_i \in \mathbb{R^n};1 \leq i \leq n \}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$ consisting of eigenvectors. The corresponding eigenvalues are $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=2}^{n}$, which means $A\varphi_i=\lambda_i\varphi_i$.

Now I've got to show, that $\exp\left(tA\right)\varphi_i=e^{\lambda_it}\varphi_i$.

I'm asking myself, if this is trivial, because $A\varphi_i=\lambda_i\varphi_i$, we get $A=\lambda_i$ and therefore the assertion $\exp(tA)\varphi_i=\exp(t\lambda_i)\varphi_i=e^{\lambda_it}\varphi_i$. Is this right or is there another way to prove it?

Comment: How do you get that $A=\lambda_i$? $\lambda_i$'s are mere scalars and $A$ is a matrix.

Comment: Saying $A=\lambda_i$ is a reasonable and intuitive substitution, but what is that actually supposed to mean mathematically?

Comment: I was totally wrong. I didn't see it. Of course it's nonsense.

Comment: Try using the series representation of the exponential function. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: $A$ is diagonalizable, so you can decompose it into a linear combination of projections $P_i$ onto its eigenspaces such that $P_iP_j=P_jP_i=0$ when $i\ne j$. From there, use the series definition for the exponential.